# Extracting the constant term

Tags: expression-manipulation, coefficients

#### Finite difference problem

There are a large number of variables, interacting at most five at a time. A sample term is:

[image]

#### How to extract the constant term?

In this example, the constant term is -1/4.

Comment: `expr /. _Subscript :> 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Total[Map[If[Total[Grad[#, Variables[expr]]] === 0, #, Nothing] &, MonomialList[expr]]]
(*-(1/4)*)
```

In general, when there are no subscripts, we proceed as Bob Hanlon indicates:

```
expr/. Thread[Variables[expr] -> 0]
```

Another way to do it is as follows:

```
Total[Map[If[Total[Exponent[#, Variables[expr]]] === 0, #, Nothing] &,MonomialList[expr]]]
 (*-(1/4)*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Part[CoefficientArrays[
  1/4 (-1 - Subscript[φ, 49, 50] - Subscript[φ, 50, 49]) + 
   Subscript[φ, 50, 50]], 1]
```

> -(1/4)